# Examples of config.yaml for printing

Tags: geoserver, wms, pdf, mapfish, config.yaml

I've been reading [this](http://www.mapfish.org/doc/print/configuration.html#id1), I wonder if there are config.yaml nice examples available to take a look at them.

Can some web links for the examples or output images be provided for this?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know any printing module demo with several different `config.yaml` to choose from. I would recommend to start by the examples provided in the [mapfish print GitHub repository](https://github.com/mapfish/mapfish-print/tree/development/examples/src/test/resources/examples).

Comment: Working link: https://mapfish.github.io/mapfish-print-doc/configuration.html